# Validating with regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Having some issues with validation with regular expressions in PHP. (It's an assignment for class, so don't have a lot of flexibility on how to do this, just need to make it work)

```
switch ($name) {
    case 'firstname' :
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $firstname)) {
            $fnameError = "Please enter your first name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($firstname)) {
            $fnameError = "Please enter your first name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
```

^^ here the regular expression does not work (anything gets through the validation)

```
case 'zip' :
        if (!preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $zip)) {
            $zipError = "Standard 5-digit zip codes only. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($zip)) {
            $zipError = "Standard 5-digit zip codes only. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
```

^^ here the regular expression DOES work
This makes me think I just don't have the right regular expression, but I can't figure out what the right one would be... I want to disallow any numbers or symbols, and accept only letters.

Here is the entire switch statement:

```
switch ($name) {
    case 'firstname' :
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $firstname)) {
            $fnameError = "Please enter your first name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($firstname)) {
            $fnameError = "Please enter your first name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
    case 'lastname' :
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $lastname)) {
            $lnameError = "Please enter your last name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($lastname)) {
            $lnameError = "Please enter your last name. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'street' :
        if (empty($street)) {
            $streetError = "Please enter your street address. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'city' :
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $city)) {
            $cityError = "Please enter your city. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($city)) {
            $cityError = "Please enter your city. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'state' :
        if ($state === "") {
            $stateError = "Please select a state. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
    case 'zip' :
        if (!preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $zip)) {
            $zipError = "Standard 5-digit zip codes only. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($zip)) {
            $zipError = "Standard 5-digit zip codes only. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'email' :
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailError = "Email invalid.";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'creditcard' :
        if ($creditCard === "") {
            $creditCardError = "Please choose a credit card. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'cc' :
        if (!preg_match('/\d{16}|\d{18}/', $ccNumber)) {
            $ccError = "Please enter a valid credit card number. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($ccNumber)) {
            $ccError = "Please enter a valid credit card number. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'cvv' :
        if (!preg_match('/\d{3}|\d{4}/', $cvv)) {
            $cvvError = "Please enter a valid CVV number. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        } else if (empty($cvv)) {
            $cvvError = "Please enter a valid CVV number. ";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
     case 'ticketnumber' :
        if (!preg_match('/^\d$/', $ticketNumber)) {
            $ticketError = "Please select your number of tickets.";
            $somethingsWrong = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php and you might not even need a regex to test if the name is valid

Comment: where you fill $firstname with value? have you checked that before the if statement, it contains the value that you expected?

Comment: Handy site https://regex101.com/

Comment: Your regex works and here is proof: http://ideone.com/RasOC5. `var_dump($firstname)` and see what it shows

Comment: It definitely has the right value (the second half that checks if it's empty works, only the first half with the regex doesn't)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I'm still not sure what's wrong, but at least I know I have the right regex

Comment: post entire  `switch($name)` statement

Comment: What's the value of `$firstname` ?